# usbip disconnecting

Tags: usb

Using a Raspberry Pi to share some USB devices (SATO label printers) over the network. It's running Raspbian 9.1 and using usbip. As the 'client', I'm running a Debian VM also on 9.1.

After a *lot* of messing around, I've got it to work, however it seems unstable and will not stay connected. From the client I found this in the logs:

```
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137257] vhci_hcd: connection reset by peer
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137421] vhci_hcd: stop threads
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137423] vhci_hcd: release socket
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137437] vhci_hcd: disconnect device
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137488] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Nov  1 16:57:03 SATOPRINT01 kernel: [ 8541.137724] usblp0: removed
```

The "connection reset by peer" thing leads me to believe it may be getting disconnected from the 'server' side (the Raspberry Pi). From the logs there:

```
Nov  1 03:37:05 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: starting usbipd (usbip-utils 2.0)
Nov  1 03:37:05 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: listening on 0.0.0.0:3240
Nov  1 03:37:05 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: listening on :::3240
Nov  1 03:37:51 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: connection from 10.36.65.102:43466
Nov  1 03:37:51 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: received request: 0x8005(7)
Nov  1 03:37:51 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: exportable devices: 1
Nov  1 03:37:51 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: request 0x8005(7): complete
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: connection from 10.36.65.102:43468
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(7)
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1.5
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 usbipd: libusbip: info: connect: 1-1.5
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 kernel: [  177.008639] usbip-host 1-1.5: stub up
Nov  1 03:38:04 satohub1 usbipd: usbipd: info: request 0x8003(7): complete
```

This looks like it corresponds to the list and then attach commands, and completes successfully. But then only a few seconds later:

```
Nov  1 03:38:09 satohub1 kernel: [  182.347684] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b9183c80
Nov  1 03:38:09 satohub1 kernel: [  182.347724] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:14 satohub1 kernel: [  187.723278] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b9183c80
Nov  1 03:38:14 satohub1 kernel: [  187.723317] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:19 satohub1 kernel: [  192.843376] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:19 satohub1 kernel: [  192.843415] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:25 satohub1 kernel: [  197.963415] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:25 satohub1 kernel: [  197.963455] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:30 satohub1 kernel: [  203.339628] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:30 satohub1 kernel: [  203.339668] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:35 satohub1 kernel: [  208.715344] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:35 satohub1 kernel: [  208.715395] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:40 satohub1 kernel: [  213.835524] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:40 satohub1 kernel: [  213.835563] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:46 satohub1 kernel: [  218.955401] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b8c61a00
Nov  1 03:38:46 satohub1 kernel: [  218.955439] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:46 satohub1 kernel: [  219.417673] usbip-host 1-1.5: usb_set_interface done: inf 0 alt 0
Nov  1 03:38:59 satohub1 kernel: [  232.691395] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b0330600
Nov  1 03:38:59 satohub1 kernel: [  232.691414] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:38:59 satohub1 kernel: [  232.693404] usbip-host 1-1.5: usb_set_interface done: inf 0 alt 0
Nov  1 03:39:41 satohub1 kernel: [  274.717582] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b9a06d80
Nov  1 03:39:41 satohub1 kernel: [  274.717601] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:39:41 satohub1 kernel: [  274.719532] usbip-host 1-1.5: usb_set_interface done: inf 0 alt 0
Nov  1 03:40:31 satohub1 kernel: [  324.724276] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb b9a06c80
Nov  1 03:40:31 satohub1 kernel: [  324.724295] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:40:31 satohub1 kernel: [  324.726658] usbip-host 1-1.5: usb_set_interface done: inf 0 alt 0
Nov  1 03:56:52 satohub1 kernel: [ 1305.449249] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlink urb afcd2f00
Nov  1 03:56:52 satohub1 kernel: [ 1305.449270] usbip-host 1-1.5: unlinked by a call to usb_unlink_urb()
Nov  1 03:56:52 satohub1 kernel: [ 1305.451784] usbip-host 1-1.5: usb_set_interface done: inf 0 alt 0
```

Obviously the timezone is not right on the Pi which makes this a little difficult. I've fixed that up now and will confirm whether the timings correspond between the two logs.

Can anyone see any obvious reasons why this would be happening?

Comment: Are you connected through wifi or ehternet?

Comment: Wi-Fi. Think that will make a difference?

Comment: Try with wired ethernet if you can, wifi delays are 10-100 times longer even when not loosing packets. If you can't use wired ethernet try to disable all power saving features of your wifi.